# Wordpress Issues renaming IMG folder

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

i have a problem with a Wordpress update. I have a /blog/ folder in my /public.html folder where is laying also my wordpress install.
I have posts with a category "blog" and when i update my wordpress my site breaks.
There is a confrontation between the two i guess.
I've fixed the problem with my .htaccess file but on a WP Update the .htaccess gets overwriten and the problem comes up again.
I need to find a way to rename my /blog/ folder without loosing my links or having to re-upload everything again. As the /blog/ folder contains mainly img uploads used for posts in my blog.

TLDR: I have a folder named Blog in my WP directory and a category Blog both dont get along well. I need to rename Blog (folder) without having to re-upload all my images. 5 years worth of img uploading.

Comment: You can change the permission of the .htaccess file and then it won't be overwritten during an update.

Comment: Nice, that sounds like a pretty good idea. Im going to try it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @cgee **NEVER** beg for random upvotes on your questions... If you think you answered the question from the OP, then write an answer and he'll accept it.

Comment: And lock the htaccess will probably not solve the issue and can cause some severe issues later. @JpTo How about renaming the folder, then replace every occurence of this folder url in the database? You could do that by exporting / open in text editor / search and replace / importing the database. Or with [SearchDBreplace](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/).

Comment: Im currently backening my WP which is taking soo loong and i havent tried changing permissions yet. I will try what you said. Thanks.